# How to add white space at the last position of a string?

Tags: swift4

I am trying to add 2 white space at the last position of a string but when I set this in a label I found no space. But if I added 2 white space with another character, it works ok. Then I tried to add 2 white space with some extra character and then trim these extra characters. But for all these case I observed no space when I placed this in a text label. I am trying this for the right alignment.

```
let name: String = self.cityModelArr[indexPos].countryShortName+"  12"
let endIndex = name.index(name.endIndex, offsetBy: -2)
let truncated = String(name[..<endIndex])
self.testLabel.text = truncated
```

I have tried some more solutions from the internet but failed to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally normal, the label removes the spaces when you preview it on screen.

You can avoid this using a ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER character (U+200C), like in this case:

```
label = "Here I want a space:  \u{200c}"
```

Comment: I had also tried this solution and result was same.
let name: String = self.cityModelArr[indexPos].countryShortName+"  \u{200c}"
self.testLabel.text = name

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to right too much code for that

```
  let name: String = self.cityModelArr[indexPos].countryShortName+"  12"
  let endIndex = name.index(name.endIndex, offsetBy: -2)
   let truncated = String(name[..<endIndex])
   self.testLabel.text = truncated
```

only you need that code:-

```
   let name: String = "your string" + String(repeating: " ", count: 2)//Your Space count like your want 2
   self.testLabel.text = name
   Response:-  "your string  "
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use \t at end of string to add space.

```
self.testLabel.text = "\(self.cityModelArr[indexPos].countryShortName)\t"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your string like

```
let strData = "This is testing string" 

 self.lblText.text = "\(strData) "
```